# Three.js store camera rotation and apply to camera dolly

Tags: three.js

I'm developing a VR app and I'm attempting to store the current camera viewing angle with

```
THREE.Utils = {
    cameraLookDir: function(camera) {
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
        vector.applyEuler(camera.rotation, camera.eulerOrder);
        return vector;
    }
};

var dir = THREE.Utils.cameraLookDir(camera);

var defaults = {
    x:dir.x,
    y:dir.y,
    z:dir.z,
    fov: camera.fov
};
```

I'm then attempting to apply this to a dolly which I use to pre-set the camera viewing angle for using with VRControls

The dolly is constructed as

```
    dolly = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
    dolly.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    scene.add( dolly );
    dolly.add( camera );
```

and I try and apply the angle so the camera is facing the same way

```
        dolly.rotation.x = defaults.x;
        dolly.rotation.y = defaults.y;
        dolly.rotation.z = defaults.z;
```

This isn't' really working, and I'm not really sure how to go about getting the camera to face the same way as it's saved values.

Any clues on how to go about this?

Comment: It seems VR control or camera control overwrite the rotation you set. In these control's frame loop, camera rotation will be set to a new angle calculated by control.

Comment: Yep that's why I use a dolly. It's a standard trick to overcome this.

Comment: I tried this way and failed. I was recommended to fork control implementation and add some sort of logic to manually update rotation.

Comment: No this part works fine. I can change the angle of the dolly and adjust the camera, I'm just not quite getting the right values.

Comment: I think you can't use direction vector to set rotation because the rotation is Euler. how about use Matrix?